# Tomcat 7 - Retrieve the version of a webapp (versioned WAR)

Tags: version, versioning, war, tomcat7

I've been unable to find any easy way of figuring out the version string for a WAR file deployed with Tomcat 7 versioned naming (ie app##version.war). You can read about it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) and what it enables [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/zero-downtime-deployment-and-rollback.html).

It'd be nice if there was a somewhat more supported approach other than the usual swiss army knife of reflection powered ribcage cracking:

```
final ServletContextEvent event ...
final ServletContext applicationContextFacade = event.getServletContext();
final Field applicationContextField = applicationContextFacade.getClass().getDeclaredField("context");
applicationContextField.setAccessible(true);
final Object applicationContext = applicationContextField.get(applicationContextFacade);
final Field standardContextField = applicationContext.getClass().getDeclaredField("context");
standardContextField.setAccessible(true);
final Object standardContext = standardContextField.get(applicationContext);
final Method webappVersion = standardContext.getClass().getMethod("getWebappVersion");
System.err.println("WAR version: " + webappVersion.invoke(standardContext));
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution is using the same version (SVN revision + padding as an example) in `.war`, `web.xml` and `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` properties files, so you could retrieve the version of these files later in your APP or any standard tool that read version from a JAR/WAR

See [MANIFEST.MF *version-number*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution described [here](http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/04/17/tomcat-v7-parallel-deployment/) uses the path name on the server of the deployed WAR. You'd extract the version number from the string between the "##" and the "/"

```
runningVersion = StringUtils.substringBefore(
                 StringUtils.substringAfter(
                     servletConfig.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"),
                     "##"),
                 "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Tomcat versions 9.0.32, 8.5.52 and 7.0.101, the webapp version is exposed as a ServletContext attribute with the name `org.apache.catalina.webappVersion`.

Link to the closed enhancement request: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64189

Comment: Im getting this variable empty. Is it necessary to to do some configuration or should it work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for Tomcat to make the version available via a ServletContext attribute (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.webappVersion) or similar. The patch to do that would be trivial. I'd suggest opening an enhancement request in Tomcat's Bugzilla. If you include a patch then it should get applied fairly quickly.