# How do you get the version number of a web app deployed to tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have deployed a .war file to a tomcat server and tomcat correctly displays the version number of my '.war' file in the manager view. The name of my '.war' file is e.g. MyApp##1.0.2.war

I would like to display the version number of my application at the bottom of all my web pages.

Is there a way to get the deployed version number?

Or should I be setting my app version number in a different manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't specify as what you use for your web pages. Your question seems duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230310/tomcat-7-retrieve-the-version-of-a-webapp-versioned-war). Anyway, its just a piece of info and your target is to make that info available to your pages.

Comment: Thanks @SabirKhan, I'll give that a try.